# Hi, I am using Codeigniter and i am looking to connect to database dynamically. Can any one help me

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.2.1, i need to pass variable from controller to module's constructor. I searched a lot in google but not getting proper answers.

Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

For reference check below link

http://www.revillweb.com/tutorials/codeigniter-tutorial-learn-codeigniter-in-40-minutes/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answe and I got the answer. It will done with the help of session

In controller we need to do store values in session

$session_array = array('session_name' => $varianle_name);

$this->session->set_userdata('name',$session_array);

And In model we need do this

$this->session->user data['name']['session_name']